# Moving mouse in the game window stops the game (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

PROBLEM:

if my mouse cursor is outside the window my game runs but if i have my cursor inside console gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/jackw/Desktop/New folder/main.py", line 36, in <module>
    if event.type == pg.QUIT():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

heres my code

```py
import pygame as pg
from Config import *
from bin import *
# initialising pygame
pg.init()

class Game():

    def background(self,background):

        window.blit(background, (0,0))





# defining classes for use
g = Game()

# game loop
while isrunning:

    # making sure the game is running on a constant clock

    time.tick(fps)

    # add background

    g.background(gameback)

    # setting up events 
    for event in pg.event.get():
        # closing window event
        if event.type == pg.QUIT():
            isrunning = False
        # input events


    # show finished frame 
    pg.display.flip()


# Last code before closing the window


# closing the window
pg.quit()
```

most variables are defined in different files
[config file](https://drizzy.is-terrible.com/qwiScq)
[gamevars file](https://drizzy.is-terrible.com/xRi0mb)

this program works fine on macOS I'm only getting this error on windows 10.
here's a [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7fy7uhsugr969m/S7R_screen.mp4?dl=0) of the bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pg.QUIT is an enumeration value.  It's basically an integer.  Your code added parentheses for some reason; this is invalid syntax.  Use merely

```
if event.type == pg.QUIT:
```

What you coded is vaguely like

```
if event.type == 4():
```

Answer (score 2):

`QUIT` is not a method or function, it is an enumerator constant, which specifies the type of the event (See [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event)).

Remove the brackets to solve the issue:

<s>`if event.type == pg.QUIT():`</s>

```py
if event.type == pg.QUIT:
```